# Java loop through certain numbers inside a for loop

Tags: java

I know how to loop through 0-200 I'm wondering how would I be able to perform an action if a player is between 2 certain number x & x and perform an action if they're between theses.

For example
The Max Number is 200:

0-9:
Perform an Action
10-29
Perform an Action different action
30-49
Perform an Action different action
so on so forth,

I'm assuming you understand what I'm trying to accomplish,  So how how would I do such a thing?

Comment: You could just have a few if statements that do different things depending on the iteration number

Comment: @CryptJunior if my answer satisfies your question could you please accept using the tick next to the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
{
     if(0<=i&&i<=9)
     {
          //do something
     }

     if(10<=i&&i<=29)
     {
          //do something
     }

     if(30<=i&&i<=49)
     {
          //do something
     }
}
```